# Download attribute on <a> tag not working in Edge

Tags: angular, html

I use the following piece of HTML to let a user download documents from the server:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let document of documents">
      <td><a href="/api/file/GetDocumentById?id={{document.id}}" download="{{document.name}}">{{document.name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Here, the download attribute sets the name of the downloaded file. This works in Chrome, but I just discovered that when using Edge, the file gets the name of the controller (GetDocumentById) instead.

Does anyone have an easy solution that sets the name of the downloaded file correctly?

Comment: I can't confirm it, but the issue may be that the server is responding with the incorrect mime type which does not match the file extension in the `download` attribute. Possibly it is a deliberate Edge feature to make it harder to accidentally download an executable as '.txt'? When using `href=data:text/csv;base64,` you can provide the mime type, and then the download attribute works as expected. I can't find a solution for our use-case though, stuck with the raw filename :/

Answer (score 1):

Download attribute is supported in following version of edge browser, make sure you are using edge version >= 17

Reference: https://caniuse.com/#search=download

[image]

Comment: It is not supported on 17 either it seems. However, What I'm looking for is an alternative